# Maclaurin Series of $\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponentiation

Calculate the Maclaurin series of $$\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1} $$ I've tried to calculate it but the series $\frac{1}{e^{2x}-1}$ divides by 0 when x is equal to 0

Comment: Fortunately, the numerator is also $0$ when $x = 0$, so that does not turn out to be a problem.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate. There is one difference though: the original question has $x$ where you have $2x$. This is a tiny difference, however.